# rmongodb: $exists gives empty result

Tags: r, rmongodb

I am running mongodb query in R using rmongodb. I need to find whether certain field exists or not in the document. However, $exists doesnot produce any result. Here is sample code used for the query.

```
library(rmongodb)
> mongo <- mongo.create(host="localhost")
> dbns <- mongo.get.database.collections(mongo, db="namedisambiguation") 
> buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
> mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "name")
[1] TRUE
> mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$exists", 1L)
[1] TRUE
> qrbson <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
> cur <- mongo.find(mongo, ns=dbns, query=qrbson)
> qrbson
    name : 3     
        $exists : 16     1

> mongo.cursor.next(cur)
[1] FALSE
```

I have tried this query using TRUE, "True", "true", 1 instead of 1L, but all of these produces same result. I have checked this query in mongo console and the result is as needed. But in R, its producing empty. Am I doing wrong somewhere or anything ?

Comment: Monday morning humor:  it's good to know there are no "$exists" any more.  Gender equality at last! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem and I guess it's a bug.

But what you could do is something along these lines here - code is tested with my database:

```
ns <- "test.things"
qs1 <- '{ "label": { "$exists": true } }'   # field exists
qs2 <- '{ "none": { "$exists": true } }'    # field does not exist

mongo.count( mongo, ns, qs1 )
[1] 9

mongo.count( mongo, ns, qs2 )
[1] 0
```

If you need to check whether two fields exist in one document, your `JSON` should look like this:

```
qs3 <- '{ "name": { "$exists": true }, "schoolname": { "$exists": true } }'
```

This should get you to the desired result, although it's a bit different from your original approach in that is uses the `JSON` notation. From the `rmongodb` documentation for `mongo.find()`

> **Arguments**
> ...
>
> *query*  ...
>
> Alternately, query may be a valid JSON character string which will be converted
> to a mongo.bson object by mongo.bson.from.JSON().

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked for the single query and its exactly what my question demands. However, my actual problem was to "and" qs1 and qs2 like {$and: [{name: {$exists: 1}}, {schoolname: {$exists: 1}}]}. I just tried doing like you seggested but still its not working  and produces -1 as result

Comment: Hi, there is currently an issue in the JSON converter for $and and $or queries. Check for this issue on github: https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/17
I hope to provide a solution soon.